Solutions to Recurences
I am currently learning various techniques in order to solve recurrences. One of which is the generalized master's theorem. The current problem I am attempting is as follows 
$H(n) < 4H(2n/5) + H(3n/5) + 2n^2$
 This isn't in the form I am used to seeing as this is an inequality. However I figured I would solve this using generalized master's theorem and then write my solution in terms of big o.
$K = 2$,
$\alpha_1 = 4$,
$\beta_1 = 2/5$,
$\alpha_2 = 1$,
$\beta_2 = 3/5$,
$\gamma = 2$
$\Gamma = 4(2/5)^2 + 1(3/5)^2 = 4(4/25) + 1(9/25) = 16/25 + 9/25 = 1$
Since $\Gamma$ is equal to 1 we get the case of $n^\gamma log n$
Am I wrong for saying the solution to this recurrence is $O(n^2logn)$?
Are there any other ways I can use to solve this problem?

Try substituting $H(n)=c n^2 \log n$ and see whether a positive value of $c$ satisfies the ineqality. This will verify whether the derived upper bound is correct or not. But it won't tell you whether it is tight or loose.
Apart from using the master's method, you can directly approach the problem using a recurrence tree: see this example.
